# Energy dissipation due to displacement current

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, capacitance, dissipation, poynting-vector

Consider the following problem:

An isolated capacitor made of parallel circular plates of radius $a$ separated by a distance $d \gg a$ is charged such that there is a potential difference $V$ between its plates. At their centre, the plates are connected by a thin straight wire of high resistance $R$, over which they discharge. Calculate the Poynting vector $\bf S$ inside the capacitor and the energy flux $P$ through a concentric cylindrical surface of radius $r<a$.

The answers are<sup>1</sup> $${\bf S} ={\bf E \times H} =-\frac{V^2}{2\pi r Rd} \left(1-\frac{r^2}{a^2} \right) {\bf \hat r}$$ and $$P=\int_{\text{cylinder}} {\bf S}\cdot \mathrm d {\bf A}=\frac{V^2}{R}\left(1-\frac{r^2}{a^2}\right)$$

where ${\bf \hat r}$ is the radial unit vector pointing outwards and $r$ is the perpendicular distance to the wire.

We therefore have a net energy flow towards the resistive wire (as expected). However, the energy dissipated in the resistance is $V^2 \over R$, which is *not* equal to $P$.

The additional term "$-r^2/a^2$" in the expression for $\bf S$ comes from the displacement current, which is non-zero here because the $\bf D$-field decreases since the charge stored on the plates decreases.

**Question:** Is the mismatch between $P$ and $V^2 \over R$ a violation of energy conservation (probably not)? How can it be explained?

**Guess:** Considering Poynting's theorem in its full form, one would possibly have to account for the energy in the electromagnetic field, although I am not sure how to do this exactly.

(Related question: [Poynting vector of a wire between capacitors](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/44127/poynting-vector-of-a-wire-between-capacitors/44191#44191))

---

1. This can be derived from the electric field ${\bf E}=\frac{V}{d}{\bf \hat z}$ and magnetic field ${\bf H}=\frac{V}{2\pi r R}\left(1-\frac{r^2}{a^2}\right){\bf \hat \theta}$, where cylindrical coordinates are used.